# `Server Error in '/' Application. No such host is known

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dns

I am getting this error on one website which is deployed in IIS , when i browse from network system i am getting this error .

other websites are working fine

```
`Server Error in '/' Application.

 No such host is known

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web          request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it      originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request.     Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[SocketException (0x2af9): No such host is known]
  System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByAddress(IPAddress address, Boolean includeIPv6)     +3192148
  System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress) +8777246
  _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +320
  System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
  System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean         includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3178`enter code here`

 Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET        Version:4.0.30319.18055'`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is one **unhanded exception** when you call the [Dns.GetHostEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998(v=vs.110).aspx) as seen on the stack trace, and on the clear message that you have.

Wrap this part of the code with try/catch and log the error on your system. If its critical for you to know the dns name, then you need to show an error page with further instructions.